# Best practises for making Java GUI's with Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, conventions, calling-convention

I am planning to make a large project, which will be using Java Swing in order to create a GUI.

When I code each frame, how am I meant to set up the file using best practise. I see different people use different things such as:

- Create an initialise UI function which shows all of the UI components
- While others just put it into the constructor of the frame

**What is the best practise for structuring your code in order to make a scalable Java GUI using Swing?**

Comment: *While others just put it into the constructor of the frame* - you should NOT put the code in the constructor of the frame because you should NOT be extending JFrame. You only extend a class when you add functionality to the class. Adding components to a frame is not adding functionality to the frame.

Comment: @camickr If I put my code in the constructor I can have it set up in a way that I do not need to extend JFrame, which I am now considering bad practise. I can make an object outside of the constructor, which is a JFrame and then use that in the constructor, or should I use some sort of `initialiseGUI()` function?

Comment: Just as a hint I strongly recommend JavaFX for these sorts of projects because the Gui components look much better than those of swing.

Comment: @J.Lengel I will be using the FlatLaf lookAndFeel in order to make my GUI look good: https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/

Comment: I hadn't heard about that before. That's pretty neat :)

Comment: "Best practise" is a broad brush. You should edit your question to focus on your *specific* question, otherwise, it looks like you're asking for a tutorial, which is not allowed here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I do have advice on this for you.

I recommend you use Model-View-Controller (MVC) architecture. Here is an example of how you'd do this using Poker.

1. Start with the model: What are the data elements you need in poker?

`Player` class, to keep track of money
`Card` class, to represent cards
`Hand` class, to represent a player's Hand

2. Next, implement the controller

`PokerGame` class, that keeps track of the players and their Cards/Hands, as well as their options to raise, stay, and fold on their turn.

3. Once you have your Model and your Controller tested and working, THEN you start to build a (SWING) GUI around it.

Start with putting the foundations of the GUI in place first.

Comment: So I should create a class for each component of the GUI that extends the object. For example I have a class called `MyGUI` and I want to add a `JLabel` I should make a sub-class extending `JLabel` and define attributes in there? and then I can repeat for each frame in the GUI, as I understand from this post.

Comment: @TheManWhoNeedsToMakeAGreatGUI "*So I should create a class for each component of the GUI that extends the object... I want to add a JLabel I should make a sub-class extending JLabel and define attributes in there?*" why? Which part of this answer made you think so?

Comment: @Pshemo I got it from keeping track of different objects i may need such as "A `Player` class, to keep track of money" So I interpreted that as a class to handle a specific frame of the GUI with components in different classes for it to be tracked.